# How to deploy React Components without CDN?

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs, react-day-picker

I made a small React app and want to deploy as a part of my Django project.

I have been using [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) to deploy my React app only with React CDNs, and this is my first time to deploy with [react-day-picker](http://react-day-picker.js.org/) which does not have a CDN. Here are my settings for my app:

rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput', 'jquery'],
  globals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput':'DayPickerInput'
  },
  entry: 'src/index.js',
  dest: 'build/js/taskmanager.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: ['react']
    }),
  ],
};
```

.babelrec

```
{
  "presets": ["react"],
  "plugins": [
    "external-helpers"
  ]
}
```

Should I rollup react-day-picker too?

Update: Found a workaround. Will update.

Comment: I see that `react-day-picker` has CDN. You can add it into HTML header http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: @hgiasac You are right! I have an error though. It is complaining about dots in the name of  "window.daypicker.input". Do you know how to import this component as DayPickerInput?

Comment: You should make `window` global, then import `window` and call `window.DayPicker.Input`. Rollup can not reference nested object